# safe way to reduce 200V to ~20 volts?

Tags: voltage-measurement

edit2:  After calling customer service, the impedance is 350k.  Does this change anything?

I am totally clueless when it comes to circuitry,  but am trying to build a grid charger for my old hybrid car, using an online DIY write-up. This charges the battery at a constant current (350-600ma selected )  and the voltage is monitored as it rises from a low of ~120v absolute min to ~ 195 volt absolute max.  I want to add to the setup by monitoring this with a voltmeter display that measures 0-33v, so a logical way to do this would be to divide the voltage by 10.  It seems to be unsafe to just use resistors to achieve this, as I understand this will be dissipating some 30-40w of heat. What is a safe (and preferably efficient) way to do this?

I need to use this particular display because of its <s>accuracy</s> precision, as I only know to stop charging when the voltage stops rising, and the voltage change will be extremely slight (0.1v/hr) at the end of an extended charge.

edit: the intended display is a self powered [Drok 5 digit DC](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CJR9QB6).  I did not see any info on impedance. Am I correct in assuming a self powered voltmeter has no or negligible impedance?

Comment: Your heat dissipation values only hold true if the meter consumes substantial current. Measure the input resistance of the voltmeter, then see if your divider really dissipates 30-40 watts, or maybe just 3 or 4 watts, or .3 to .4 watts.

Comment: Are you powering this from it's own power supply, or from the line you want to measure? And is it DC or AC it's measuring?

Comment: what ?!! Hybrid card charger 350-600mA ?? what are you trying to charge is more like an RC car battery !

Comment: Your resistor assumption is wrong. You can use mega-ohm resistors to divide the voltage, and they will dissipate milliwatts.

Comment: @ElectronS it is a trickle charger to exercise the battery a few times a year.  it is discharged below normal range allowed by the car's computer, then slowly recharged to erase cell memory.  this is more for battery life than an actual recharging.  The car charges at pulses of up to 50A short term (Honda Insight Gen 1).

Comment: The measurement inputs on volt meters have high impedance, which means they draw only a very little current. 1M is typical on cheap digital meters 10M or more on the expensive ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you've got one of those 3 wire LED voltmeters with red yellow and black wires

You'll probably find that an ordinary 100 to 220V AC to USB adaptor can be connected to the 100 to 195VDC and will produce 5V at reasonable efficiency which will be enough to power the voltmeter, (red and black wires)

for the measurement side add a series resistor to get the appropriate scaling. if your meter has 1 megaohm input impedance a 9 megaohm resistor in series with the white wire will reduce 195V down to 19.5V, (connect the black wire also to battery negative)

Check the data sheet for the resistor, some cheap resistors are not suited for continuous use at 200V, adding a fuse in series with the resistor is probably not a bad idea either.

The impedance of the meter can be determined by hooking it up to a low voltage source (eg: 12V)  measuring that and then adding resistors in series with the yellow wire until the reading halves. (the added resistance then matches the meter impedance)
You need nine times that to get a one-tenth reading.

Some meters  have a solder jumper on the back of the meter that can be moved to shift the decimal point, but I suspect that yours is not one of them.

Comment: This is an old question, but for future people:If you're using a cheap meter, you might have issues with the input impedance. Basically, your meter will act like a resistor in parallel with the 1MOhm resistor, decreasing the resistance and decreasing the voltage, giving an underestimate of the voltage.

Comment: yeah that's why I did not suggest using an external meter during the modification. just add resistors and see how the meter responds, using the meter itself to measure the modification

Comment: apologies, you're correct, i misread your answer

Answer (score 5):

What is the input impedance of your voltmeter? If it's 1 Mohm, you could use a 1 Mohm/100k divider (the absolute accuracy would be poor, like 10%, but you care about trends, not accuracy) and the total power in the divider would be a max of about 36 milliwatts. A 100k/10k divider would provide accuracy of about 1%, and only dissipate 360 mW.

You don't need absolute accuracy, since if nothing else the battery voltage will change with temperature. What you're trying to do is detect small changes (or lack thereof), and the absolute accuracy is irrelevant to that task. What you care about is stability, and with low power dissipation this ought to be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way forwards here is to use a passive potential divider network as you've already suggested.  If you make the total resistance of the potential divider = 1M, then the power dissipation will be very small.

In order to prevent the input impedance of your monitor affecting the output of the high impedance potential divider, feed the output of the potential divider into an OpAmp stage set up as a unity gain amplifier.  Then connect your monitor to the output of the OpAmp.